# GIT getting 2 branches from another machine onto mine

Tags: git

I'm new to git so I'm setting up a git workflow to get the hang of it and I'm not sure how to get a branch on another machine onto mine, I've got 2 branches on my desktop:

```
master
release-0.1
```

The remote has these 2 branches too:

```
master
release-0.1
```

Then there's my laptop which has an old copy of master that needs to be deleted, and 2 other branches not on either remote or my desktop:

```
master (deleting)
new-feature-a
new-feature-b
```

I'm new to git so I'm not really sure what I should do, I want to work on **new-feature-a** on my desktop now and only work on **new-feature-b** on the laptop. Should I push **new-feature-a** to **origin/new-feature-a** then pull it to the desktop? Then once the feature is complete push it to the **release-0.1** branch then merge it into master?

- Should I keep a copy of master locally?

Comment: "Should I keep a copy of master locally?"  this is a really smart question

Answer (score -1):

Here's what I would do

On the laptop

- Commit all changes to **new-feature-a**
- Push to remote

On Desktop

- Pull **new-feature-a**
- make changes and commit
- Check out **release-0.1**
- Merge with  **new-feature-a**
- Push **release-0.1**
- Pull **master**
- Merge with **release-0.1**
- PUsh **master**

Yes, you will need the local copy of master if you wan to merge it with the new features.

Comment: "Yes, you will need the local copy of master if you wan to merge it with the new features."   Depending on what "a local copy" means to you, this is untrue.   There's no need to have a local branch corresponding to a remote, just to merge it.